# I want to count value numbers which is dynamic from db using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to count value numbers which type is equal to 0 using Laravel. Thanks.
[image]

**controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['fundraise'] =  Fundraised::get();    
        return view('fundraise',$data);
    }
```

**Html View**

```
         @if(count($fundraise) > 0)
              @foreach ($fundraise as $value)
              <li>
                <a class="fundRaiserItem" href="">
                  <img src="{{config('markaz.file_url').$value->icon}}" alt="Icon">
                  <h3 class="fundRaisedCount">{{$value->number}}</h3>
                  <h5 class="fundRaisedTitle">{{$value->name}}</h5>
                </a>
                </li>
                 @php
                     $numbersValue = $value->where('type',0)->pluck('number');
                       $val = numbersValue->count();
                       dd($val);
                 @endphp
              @endforeach
              @endif
```

Comment: Do you want to "count" the rows with type "0"? You can do it on the controller instead and pass it to the blade template.

Comment: i want to plus the value of column number which is type 0

Answer (score 1):

The eloquent collection is [filterable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where) and [countable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-count):

```php
public function index()
    {
        $data['fundraise'] =  Fundraised::get();
        $data['zero_count'] =  $data['fundraise']->where('type', 0)->sum('number');
        return view('fundraise',$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```php
$data  = DB::table('Your Table Name')->where('type','=',0)->get();
```

Step 2:

```php
$countData  = count($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You called `Fundraised::get()` which means get all `Fundraised` and it's a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

Note that `$value` in  `@foreach ($fundraise as $value)` is single model object,
and it won't work if you try `$value->where('type',0)->pluck('number')` because `where` or `pluck` methods are available on model collection, so simply try your code with calling `where` and `pluck` on `$fundraise` variable. i.e:

```
@php
    $val = $fundraise->where('type',$value->type)->count();
    dd($val);
@endphp
```

As [@shaedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7451109/shaedrich) commented the best way is to pass all data at once to your blade and avoid using `@php` tag in your blade

```
$data['fundraise'] =  Fundraised::get();
$data['zero_count'] =  $data['fundraise']->where('type', 0)->sum('number');
return view('fundraise',$data);
```

Comment: Using `@php` should be avoided in blade templates when possible. This logic belongs to the controller

Comment: Whether you pluck the number column or not doesn't change the result of `count()` as far as I am concerned.